# search in one file given patterns from another one

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep, ksh

I am serching for a compact/elegant solution for this problem in linux shell (ksh if possible).

Given 2 files, both containing lines with a constant structure, eg:

file A

```
354guitar..06
948banjo...05
123ukulele.04
```

file B

```
354bass....04
948banjo...04
```

i would like to loop someway on file A, and search for lines in file B having same content in position 4-11, but different content in position 12-13.

For case above i would expect second line of file B as output, having "banjo..." matching second line of file A and 05!=04.

I was thinking to use awk, but can't find a solution by myself :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really simple with awk:

```
$ awk '{a=substr($0,4,8);b=substr($0,12,2)}NR==FNR{c[a]=b;next}a in c&&c[a]!=b' fileA fileB
948banjo...04
```

Or in a more readable format, you can saver the following in a script name file.awk

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{ # This is executed for every input line (both files)
        a=substr($0,4,8) # put characters 4 through 11 to variable a
        b=substr($0,12,2) # put characters 12 and 13 to variable b
}
NR==FNR{  # This is executed only for the first file 
        c[a]=b  # store into map c index a, value b
        next # Go to the next record (remaining commands ignored)
}
# The remaining is only executed for the second file (due to the next command)
(a in c) && (c[a] != b) # if a is an index of the map c, and the value
                        # we previously stored is not the same as the current b value
                        # then print the current line (this is the default acttion)
```

and execute like:

```
awk -f file.awk fileA fileB
```

Comment: wonderful, thanks a lot! It would be good to have a short explanation of what it does if possible...

Comment: @Pintun Added some explanations. Comment here if something is still missing

Answer (score 1):

You could use a zsh one-liner such as this one :

```
for line in `cat fileA`; do grep '^\d\{3\}$line[4,11]' fileB | grep -v '$line[12,14]$'; done
```

Comment: This also works, but it would probably safer to write it as `while read -r -d$'\n' line; do .... ; done < fileA`, in case the file does not fit in the command buffer, or in case there are whitespaces in the lines.